# Maximum call stack size exceeded when i try to download some images with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend

I am doing an image gallery, with angular8 and rxjs, the images are stored in my google drive account, when the portfolio module is loaded(lazily) my app calls the backend obtaining an array of google file's obj containing metadata and the link to the src,
the link is something like : 
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rgYp8Nnw_4Achh7PqHWM-0EGNz9JRQETbfSV-I1cPdLkLK5h3FVgd-SXO97KCBWV4PIpfSTetIG8**=s220** 
where s220 is the width of the img, if not specified the API will answer you with the full-size file

so basically my algorithm consists basically in few simple step :
- transform the array in a stream of images
- create the img obj 
- retrieve the img from google(i do not want to serve them from my be for saving money)
- return the complete image

If the image size is under a specific limit it works fine ,but, othwewise at one point, I get the error (it depend by how big the files are) I think that is due to the wrong usage of rxjs mergeAll operator but, I will leave it to the experts, you will find my code below thank you in advice for the help.

```
  public getImagesGalleryImages():Observable<Image>{
    return this.getImageList().pipe(
      map( data =>{ let res = data["files"]; return res ;}),
      map( fileArray => this.generateImage(fileArray)),
      concatAll(),
      map(image => this.x(image)),
      concatAll()
    )
  } 

  private getImageList():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.url + "app/rty");
  }

  private generateImage = (fileArray: Array<any>):Observable<Image> => {
    let res : Array<Image>  = fileArray.map(image => this.buildImage(image));
    return from(res);    
  }

  private x(image ):Observable<Image>{
   return this.gfs.loadImageData(image.srcLink).pipe(
     map(data => {
       let typedArray = new Uint8Array(data);
       let string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,typedArray);
       let base64String = window.btoa(string);
       let imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
       image.src = imageUrl;
       return of(image)
    }),
    concatAll()
   );
  }

  private buildImage(image):Image{
    let img = new Image();
    img.name = image["name"];
    img.downloadLink = image["webContentLink"];
    img.localtion = image["location"];
    img.date = new Date(image["createdTime"]);
    img.srcLink = image["thumbnailLink"];
    img.imageMediaMetadata = image["imageMediaMetadata"];
    return img;
  }

      loadImageData(link:string):Observable<ArrayBuffer>{
     let linky = link.replace("=s220",'');

     return this.http.get(linky,{responseType:"arraybuffer"},);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I don't see `concatAll()` need to be used here.

A `map()` with `concatAll()` is basically equivalent to a simple `concatMap()` (or `switchMap()` really, depends on the use case)

To name a few things worth changing:

Your `x()` can be simplified to

```
private x(image):Observable<Image>{
   return this.gfs.loadImageData(image.srcLink).pipe(
     map(data => {
       let typedArray = new Uint8Array(data);
       let string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,typedArray);
       let base64String = window.btoa(string);
       let imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
       image.src = imageUrl;
       return image;
    })
   );
  }
```

And your `getImagesGalleryImages()` can be simplified to:

```
public getImagesGalleryImages():Observable<Image>{
  return this.getImageList().pipe(
    switchMap(data => { 
        const fileArray = data["files"];
        return this.generateImage(fileArray);
    }),
    concatMap(image => this.x(image)),
  );
}
```

Also `generateImage()` can be simplified to:

```
private generateImage(fileArray: Array<any>): Observable<Image> {
  return from(fileArray.map((image) => this.buildImage(image)));
}
```